# How to auto bind dropdown list to a custom class type?

Tags: hibernate, spring-mvc, dropdown, many-to-one

I am new to Spring MVC.
I don't know how to make spring mvc set a value coming from a dropdown in a model object. I can imagine this a very common scenario

Here is the code:

**Invoice.java**

```
@Entity
public class Invoice{

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private Integer id;

    private double amount;

    @ManyToOne(targetEntity=Customer.class, fetch=FetchType.EAGER)
    private Customer customer;

    //Getters and setters
}
```

**Customer.java**

```
@Entity
public class Customer {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private Integer id;

    private String name;
    private String address;
    private String phoneNumber;

    //Getters and setters
}
```

**invoice.jsp**

```
<form:form method="post" action="add" commandName="invoice">
<form:label path="amount">amount</form:label>
<form:input path="amount" />
<form:label path="customer">Customer</form:label>
<form:select path="customer" items="${customers}" required="true" itemLabel="name" itemValue="id"/> 
<input type="submit" value="Add Invoice"/>
</form:form>
```

**InvoiceController.java**

```
@Controller
public class InvoiceController {

    @Autowired
    private InvoiceService InvoiceService;

    @RequestMapping(value = "/add", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public String addInvoice(@ModelAttribute("invoice") Invoice invoice, BindingResult result) {
        invoiceService.addInvoice(invoice);
        return "invoiceAdded";
    }
}
```

When InvoiceControler.addInvoice() is invoked, an Invoice instance received as a parameter. The invoice has an amount as expected, but the customer instance attribute is null. This is because the http post submits the customer id and the Invoice class expects a Customer object. I don't know what is the standard way to convert that.

I have read about Controller.initBinder(), about Spring Type conversion (in http://static.springsource.org/sprin...alidation.html)

Any ideas?